# Zend project - mysql not fetching UTF8

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8

I have one Zend project where I use mysql - my db connection collation is utf8_unicode_ci and my tables collation is utf8_unicode_ci. I have stored successfully some records which contain UTF8 characters but when I try to fetch them from the DB they're broken e.g.:

DVI•1500HD is fetched as DVIâ€¢1500HD

I've tried setting `resources.db.params.charset = utf8` in application.ini but it doesn't fix the problem.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding the following line to your config.

```
resource.db.params.driver_options.1002 = "SET NAMES utf8"
```

Regarding to your Zend Framework version, this command is needed to change the transfer encoding of mysql. The given command is the first thing executet when intantiating the db adapter.

Comment: It still doesn't work :( I tried before setting it directly with 
    $db = Zend_Db_Table::getDefaultAdapter(); $db->query('SET NAMES UTF8'); without success.

Comment: What Zend_Db_Adapter Class are you using. I made my best experiences with Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql.

Comment: How do yout try to fetch the databases content. If you use Zend_Db_Table but do not set the the DefaultAdapter yout adapter isn't used.

Comment: Hmmm I use classes that extend Zend_Db_Table_Abstract, I thought that defaultAdapter is set by specifying the settings in application.ini. Isn't it?

Comment: I include this in my application.ini - `resources.db.isDefaultTableAdapter = true`

Comment: I not sure at the moment whether the configuration set the defaultAdatper automatically. 
Try to create a new adpater from the config in you bootstrap, and giving this adapter to `Zend_Db_Table::setDefaultAdapter();`

Comment: This is really irritating I have to say!

Comment: I've found the problem. It's that line in my application.ini:
`resources.db.params.charset = utf8`
Thanks for the help anyway!

Comment: Now the problem is when `resources.db.params.charset = utf8` is removed, the encoding from PHP to MYSQL is broken ... crap

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the content you get from the database is UTF8, but it goes wrong in your presentation. Do you send the correct content-type header when presenting in a webpage? And is that page also saved as UTF8 document?

Answer (score 0):

I have try all the solutions from above , at the end fix with this in the freetds.conf

(/etc/freetds/freetds.conf)

[myserver]

**tds version = 8.0**

**client charset = UTF-8**